# Access an array and get the stringvalue of an element

Tags: iphone, string

i would like to know how i can access the name of an image when the syntax is something like that:

```
 NSArray* imgArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_01.png"], 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_02.png"], 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_02.png"], nil];
```

If i print out a specific index, i get the address.

```
NSLog(@"TEST: %@", [imgArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Output:

```
TEST: <UIImage: 0x4b12cd0>
```

How do i get the stringvalue?
Any ideas?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImage` does not expose the name of file it was initialized with. There is no way to access it from the image object.

Comment: Ok thanks, i understand. I´ve solved it by creating the NSArray only with stringValues and do that UIImage-loading later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the string values yourself. The `UIImage` object is somewhat closed with respect to the data backing the image.

You *could* of course subclass `UIImage` and implement

```
+(UIImage*)imageNamed:(NSString*)name
{
    self.keepName = name;
    return [super imageNamed:name];
}
```

adding a `keepName` string property, but I wouldn't see why you would.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store & retrive image from NSMutableArray than you have to take your image in UIimageView and than store it in NSMutableArray.. and from particular index you can retrieve it back.

K.D